# Latest Android Studio 2020.3.1 not showing Signature Versions option while signing APK

Tags: android, apk, signing

[image]

As showing in this photo. I recently updated my Android Studio to the latest version 2020.3.1
while signing the apk I am unable to see the version selection options.

```
targetSdkVersion 30
minSdkVersion 21
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
```

any solution please?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 8):

The signature version selection checkboxes seem to have dissappear from the UI in the latest Android Studio version, but you can still enable V1 Jar Signature during the Gradle build

Modify your app level `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
...

signingConfigs {
    release  {
        keyAlias 'key0'
        keyPassword '************'
        storeFile file('path to your key file')
        storePassword ''************''
        //Enable V1 signing 
        v1SigningEnabled true
        v2SigningEnabled true
    }
}

...

  buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        //Use the signing configuration we just defined
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
     }
  }

...
}
```

Comment: This method is not working. Just checking if anybody has found a solution to it.

Answer (score 1):

Configure gradle app level:

```
signingConfigs {
 ...
 v1SigningEnabled true
 v2SigningEnabled true
}
```

Just check that you have to add this line inside buidTypes

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        ...
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
     }
  }
```

For more detailed information, take a look at this post:

https://georgimirchev.com/2021/08/17/android-studio-arctic-fox-not-building-a-signed-apk/